# Laravel stapler reuse images

Tags: php, laravel, paperclip

I'm trying to set up the stapler package with laravel and it looks like it'll meet most of my needs.  However, one thing I'm wanting to do is have a set of 20 or so default profile images for users (similar to stackexchange I guess) that are assigned to users upon registration.

Is it possible to reuse the images without reuploading new ones?
This way a bunch of users can all use the same ~20 images and I can save a lot of storage space.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can.  What I would do is store the paths to all the images in a table.  When a user registers to your site, you can then randomly pick one from this table and assign that image to the new user.